# Losing newline characters when saving Java string to Oracle CLOB field

Tags: java, oracle, clob

I'm building a java string and adding newline characters ("\n") where I want to indicate the end of a record. I was storing this string in oracle in a VARCHAR2 field and everything was working just fine until the data I was storing grew too large for such a field. I now am trying to save the records in a CLOB, but when I retrieve the records the newline is missing.

How can I make sure that when I retrieve the data the newlines are still there?

I'd love to add code examples, but I'm working with an API that abstracts the database layer so I'm not exactly certain what it's doing. All I know is it worked when it was saving as a VARCHAR2 but as a CLOB it's gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a thread addressing the same issue:

[Are escape sequences preserved in CLOB??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982272/are-escape-sequences-preserved-in-clob)

There is no reason the CLOBs should be losing your escape characters as long as you are using the correct encodings the entire time AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread but I don't understand how it applies. What is the default encoding for a Java string? Could I specify that a Java string used UTF-8? I'm kinda lost as to how I might work around this mis-matched encoding.

Comment: The problem would not be in your java strings but in the settings to whatever API you are using for the database connection or on your database itself.  Did you specify an encoding when you created the table?  Also, can you specify an encoding when using the API you are using?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'll just replace the "\n" with another, valid delimeter. Thanks.